# Web scraping in Python using BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am relatively new to web scraping in Python. I currently have an html document that has four pages in it. I'm trying to scrape just page 2 and page 4 out of them.

How do I do that?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
import bs4
import os
soup=BeautifulSoup(open('Prod224_0055_00007464_20170930.html'),"html.parser")
Format=soup.prettify()
soup.find_all("a")
```

Which has given me this so far:

```
[<a id="PAGE1">\xa0</a>,
 <a href="#PAGE3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">3</a>,
 <a href="#PAGE4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">4</a>,
 <a id="PAGE2">\xa0</a>,
 <a href="#SECTION3">3</a>,
 <a href="#SECTION4">4</a>,
 <a href="#PAGE3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">3</a>,
 <a href="#PAGE4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">4</a>,
 <a id="PAGE3">\xa0</a>,
 <a id="SECTION1">1</a>,
 <a id="SECTION2">2</a>,
 <a id="PAGE4">\xa0</a>,
 <a id="SECTION3">3</a>,
 <a id="SECTION4">4</a>,
 <a id="SECTION5">5</a>]
```

Ideally, I would like to get Page 2 and Page 4 as they contain the data I want to read into a csv file.

Comment: TRY THIS```soup.find_all("a",{'href':'#PAGE3'})```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I realized my question was incorrect. I am actually trying to extract information from a html table and store it into a .csv file.